# How to use evaluateJavascript in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I need to encrypt a password before logging in. 
The encryption code is in javascript

```
function encrypt(password) {
    var modulus = "00b6b7f8531b19980c66ae08e3061c6295a1dfd9406b32b202a59737818d75dea03de45d44271a1473af8062e8a4df927f031668ba0b1ec80127ff323a24cd0100bef4d524fdabef56271b93146d64589c9a988b67bc1d7a62faa6c378362cfd0a875361ddc7253aa0c0085dd5b17029e179d64294842862e6b0981ca1bde29979";
    var exponent = "010001";
    var key = RSAUtils.getKeyPair(exponent,"", modulus);
    return RSAUtils.encryptedString(key, password);
}
```

the functions RSAUtils are defined earlier. (I tried this on Chrome and it worked).

I tried

```
WebView encryptor = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.encryptor);
encryptor.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
encryptor.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/encryption.html");
encryptor.evaluateJavascript("encrypt(\"" + password + "\" )", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        Log.d("encrypted password", s);
    }
});
```

and got

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: encrypt is not defined", source:  (1)
```

and

```
D/encrypted password: null
```

in logcat.

I tried to load html in a `WebView` and it was loaded correctly.

Does anyone know where this goes wrong?

Comment: It seems that it is because the webview is not fully loaded at the time. I put contructing webview to onCreate and it now works. But are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I use the webview's `onPageFinished` callback, like this:

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        encryptor.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/encryption.html");
    }
});
```